# Ionic 3 remove splashscreen and whitescreen

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 I have to create a custom splash screen. So I removed the default one. Everything is working except the white screen before the splash screen.

note: I have uninstalled the splashscreen.

Comment: i am not getting you. You have to create your custom splashscreen then you have to change default screens in the assets folder with new screens. Why have you uninstalled plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information on how to solve this in these links:

- https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/generate-a-custom-spash-screen-and-icons-in-ionic/
- https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/

Comment: I checked this already. But It is not telling about removing the splash screen and white screen.

Comment: if you have deleted the splash-screen plugin you will still see the error of the white screen. I recommended those links because they show how you can configure the splash screen correctly and if you want to add some other customization. If your intention is to modify something of the beginning of the application, as it can be an animation of when starting, similar to the one that Uber has, you should do it in a native way for each platform. In the joshmorony link you will find the way to make an animated Splash, within the limitations of Ionic / Cordova.